# unset a variable and then use its value

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

In a `source`d file, I want to return the exit status of a particular command, which I store in the variable `return_val`.

How do I unset this variable (so as not to pollute the name space), and still return it's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a shell that supports local variables, such as ksh, bash or zsh, put all the code in functions and declare all variables as local.

With plain sh, you can use `eval` to perform the variable expansion before using the value. A return status only contains digits, so you don't even need tricky quoting.

```
eval "unset return_status; return $return_status"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used STDOUT to keep a copy of the variable's contents:

```
# Unset a variable and then use its value afterwards
echo $_return_val | { unset _return_val; return "$(cat)"; }
```

Comment: The right hand side would still run in a subshell unless `lastpipe` was set (requires that job control is not in effect).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with local variables

```
return_exit () {
    local code=${!1}
    unset "$1"
    return "$code"
}
```

Then call it like:

```
return_exit _return_val
```

Comment: This does not return the value of the variable.

Comment: @TomHale: Updated

Comment: If the shell has local variables, `_return_val` should be a local variable in a function and then the problem would not arise.

Comment: @Gilles: true but local variables, in bash anyway, can only exist inside functions so that would require op put the entire source file into a function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I recommend if the shell has local variables. The useful part of the question is what to do if the shell doesn't have local variables.

Comment: This removes `$_return_val` from the namespace but adds `return_exit`. Can a function `unfunction` (`zsh`) itself? `bash`?

Answer (score -2):

Since your wish and your idea for a solution is in conflict with unspecified parts of the standard, I recommend to use an intermediate variable to store the value.

This of course only makes sense in case that you like to apply the method to more than a single variable. You could use the variable `$REPLY` that is integral part in various shells.

Note that there is no grant that `{ cmd; }` does not create a subshell, so even calling `unset` in such a construct may not apply to the main shell.

Using

```
echo "$_return_val" && unset _return_val
```

should be what you like in all cases I have in mind.